# how to write/give input for command promt while the command execute through the java program

Tags: java, windows, git, cmd, runtime

I have tried POC for my project. I am run some cmd commands are through my java program without user interaction with the help of JavaRuntime. Now I can able to run the command, but not able to give some input on runtime.

This is my sample code.

```
Process process = null;
        try {
            Runtime runtime =  Runtime.getRuntime();
            process = runtime.exec(command);
            logger.logOutput(process.getInputStream(), "Response Success : ");
            logger.logOutput(process.getErrorStream(), "Error: ");
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My sample Commands

```
"cmd /c start cmd.exe /K "E: && cd E:\Live\rsrk-node-api && git status\""
```

this above comment is executed perfectly.

My other command is: `"git pull origin master"`

now this command is needed my bitbucket password to access. I need to enter this password through the java program.

I have tried alternate way like configure ssh to my bitbucket but in the windows system every time asking password.

So please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: This unclear. The code you provided has no relevance to the issue you experience, you need to update your question and show the issue you experience and how you got to the issue you experienced.

Answer (score 0):

I would try rather:

```
cmd /C "cd /d E:\Live\rsrk-node-api && git status"
```

Note the `cd /d` part which will ensure the drive is changed.

There should be no need for `cmd ... start cmd...`

Make sure your program is running with your account, and that git config `credential.helper` is set to manager.

If you are using SSH, try first with a SSH key without passphrase.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly, and address the password part (that I initially skipped)